# Schedulers.boundedElastic() Threads are not used

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have the following code pattern where after receiving the HTTP response from the WebClient call I publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) to do some business logic transformation in order to avoid stalling the reactive thread shared by the server and WebClient  :

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<ListMailOrdersResp>> listMailOrders(@RequestParam String customerId,
                                                                         @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0")
                                                                         int orderId) {
       return client.method(HttpMethod.GET).uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/foooo")
                        .queryParam("bar", customerId)
                        .build())
                .exchangeToMono(response ->  response.bodyToMono(FooResp.class))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(response -> {

                    ListMailOrdersResp listMailOrdersResp = matchOrderId(response, customerId, orderId);

                    return new ResponseEntity<ListMailOrdersResp>(listMailOrdersResp, HttpStatus.OK);
                })
```

However I only see [reactor-http-nio-3  ] thread in the logs. I dont see any bounded elastic threads being used

Please help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I changed  the code above like so ...

```
 .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).doOnNext(s -> System.out.println(s)).log()
```

Now I can see boundElatic thread in the logs ....

22-03-2023 23:47:10.319 [**boundedElastic-1**    ] INFO  reactor.Mono.Lift.1

22-03-2023 23:47:10.320 [reactor-http-nio-3  ] INFO  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient

22-03-2023 23:47:10.353 [**boundedElastic-1**    ] INFO  reactor.Mono.Lift.1

22-03-2023 23:47:10.353 [reactor-http-nio-3  ] INFO  reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer

My confusion was because I was only seeing reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient  and reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer logs